# DNS Problem in my notebook

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, ip-address

i have windows 2003 server domain environment in my office.

my server ip is: 192.168.1.2

if i put this IP in DNS of my laptop network card my folder SYNC works fine & also internet work fine in office.

but internet did't work in my home for that i need to change DNS again to Auto & internet start working again.

its too difficult to change cause some time i don't have administrative password.

is there any solution to that?

Thanks

Comment: Discuss this with your system administrator.

Answer (score 2):

use DHCP to correctly auto-configure the DNS servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the IP of your home router to 192.168.1.2 then your laptop won't know the difference. It will, however, notice when you are neither at home or at work.